# Intersection of set of values corresponding to given keys from several dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set-intersection

I am creating a variable that measure the size of a sub-sample of values for a given key in 3 different dictionaries. For example, I want the set of values corresponding to key A1 in dictionary dict_a , to key b2 in dictionary dict_b and to key c5 in dictionary dict_c (i.e. the intersection of the set of values corresponding to given keys from 3 dictionaries).

I have written a code that does it using a loop as follows:

```
import numpy as np


dict_a = {'a1':[1,3,4], 'a2':[1,5,6,7,8,9,13]} 
dict_b = {'b1':[85,7,25], 'b2':[1,8,10,70], 'b3':[1,5,69,13], 'b4':[1,75,15,30]} 
dict_c = {'c1':[1,3,4], 'c2':[725,58,2,89], 'c3':[5,684,6,8,2], 'c4':[4,8,88,55,75,2,8], 'c5':[8,5,6,28,24,6], 'c6':[8,52,3,58,26,2]} 

keys_a =  list(dict_a.keys())
keys_b =  list(dict_b.keys())
keys_c =  list(dict_c.keys())


a= []
b= []
c= []
size = []
for y in keys_a:
    for u in keys_b:
        for w in keys_c:
            a.append(u)
            b.append(w)
            c.append(y)

            # Define subsample
            subsample = np.intersect1d(dict_a[y],dict_b[u],dict_c[w])
            size.append(len(subsample))
```

The problem is that my dictionaries are much bigger than in the example and this takes a long time to run.

Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Comment: Could you please post a sample input and output so there is no ambiguity about the expected result? Just from your example even.

Answer (score 0):

How about using sets?

```
size = []
for y in keys_a:
    for u in keys_b:
        for w in keys_c:
            common = set.intersection(set(dict_a[y]),
                                      set(dict_b[u]),
                                      set(dict_c[w]))
            size.append(len(common))
```

Calculating the intersection of sets should also be a lot faster than converting the list of numbers to arrays first and using np.intersection then.

You can use this approach with any hashable types in your lists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to chop this into a few bits. First generating the `a`, `b` and `c` lists, and then the main `size` list using numpy and finally doing the same with Python lists.

**Getting the key lists**

So if we look then `c` is actually a list of keys from `dict_a` and so on. I'm going to assume that is on purpose, but if it's not then replace `y` with `key_a` and you'll see what I mean.

We can calculate this easily up front without getting into the main loop. Each item is just repeated by the product of the number of keys in the other two lists. We can do that with something like:

```
from itertools import repeat, chain


def key_summary(dict_1, dict_2, dict_3):
    count = len(dict_2) * len(dict_3)
    return chain(*(repeat(k, count) for k in dict_1.keys()))


a = list(key_summary(dict_b, dict_a, dict_c))
b = list(key_summary(dict_c, dict_a, dict_b))
c = list(key_summary(dict_a, dict_b, dict_c))
```

This should be faster, as it's not deeply nested in the loops, but given how easy it is to calculate I think you might want to think about why you need this. Could you achieve you're goal without actually making the lists?

**Getting the size list**

I don't think you are using the `intersect1d()` function correctly. [The docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) state that the third argument is `assume_unique`, which is not what I think you are trying to do. I'm assuming you want the elements which appear in all lists one way to do that is:

```
np.intersect1d(np.intersect1d(val_a, val_b), val_c))
```

This suggests a way to optimize the loop. Instead of calculating the intersection of `val_a` and `val_b` inside every loop, we can instead do it once and re-use it.

```
for val_a in dict_a.values():
    for val_b in dict_b.values():
        # Get the intersection of a and b first
        cache = np.intersect1d(val_a, val_b)

        if not len(cache):
            # Our first two sets have nothing in common, we know that we are
            # just going to add a bunch of zeros for everything in dict_c
            size.extend(repeat(0, len(dict_c)))
        else:
            size.extend(
                len(np.intersect1d(cache, val_c)) for val_c in dict_c.values())
```

This also allows us to apply one more optimization which is to skip looping over `dict_c` at all if the intersection of `val_a` and `val_b` has nothing in it. We could also do something similar if `val_a` is ever empty.

As a final optimization you should always have `dict_a` be the smallest and `dict_c` the largest, as this gives us the best chance of skipping steps.

Doing the above netted my about 200% increase in speed (1.493ms -> 0.8ms on the example given).

**Getting the size list (using Python sets)**

I'm assuming you are using the numpy functions for a good reason, but if they aren't essential you can convert your lists to sets, which are *very* fast to perform intersections on in Python. We can follow a pretty similar approach as above:

```
dset_a = {k: set(v) for k, v in dict_a.items()}
dset_b = {k: set(v) for k, v in dict_b.items()}
dset_c = {k: set(v) for k, v in dict_c.items()}

size = []
for val_a in dset_a.values():
    for val_b in dset_b.values():
        cache = val_a & val_b

        if not cache:
            size.extend(repeat(0, len(dict_c)))
        else:
            size.extend(len(cache & val_c) for val_c in dset_c.values())
```

This is **vastly faster** on the given example. This took 0.019ms vs. 1.493ms for the original (about ~80x faster!).